# Spring Data Repository. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type:

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm having a problem with Spring Data Repository.
I create a repository and when I run my process gives me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class FextiaasDetail

The issue is that not because it throws me the error.
My class `FextiaasDetail` has hbm, and my repository is this:

```
public interface DeciDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<FextiaasDetail, Long> {
```

and I use it from this way:

```
@Autowired
private DeciDetailsRepository deciDetailsRepository;
```

This model I copied from another Repository who already walk.

Comment: Your `FextiaasDetail` is not annotated as entity properly perhaps?

Comment: I think that this isn't the problem. FextiaasDetail is equals to another entity used in other repository who already walk.

Comment: I have found that not creating me the bean , so that tells me is not an managed type

Comment: You should show us a little bit of your code...